# Move semantics + reference to member's member variable - solutions and nomenclature?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

The basic problem I've bumped into a couple of times is where class C has members of types class A and class B, and B's constructor takes a reference to A.  When you try to std::move C, the new B gets a reference to the old A, which has been invalidated by the move.

So my question: is there a name for this?  I've been googling for solutions but can't find the right search terms.

In the past my solution has been "don't do that": make B own the A and have C get the A from the B.  But I've run into a situation now where that's not going to work.  Instead I have to fix the references after the move.

I'm considering enforcing that by writing a replacement for reference_wrapper that gets invalidated by move operations.  But before I commit to that I'd like to know if there's an existing solution (e.g. boost something).

Here's some code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct A
{
    A( int x )
        : m_x( x )
        , m_ok( true )
    {
    }

    A( const A& ) = delete;
    A& operator=( const A& ) = delete;

    A( A&& other )
        : m_x( std::move( other.m_x ) )
        , m_ok( true )
    {
        other.m_ok = false;
    }

    A& operator=( A&& other )
    {
        m_x = std::move( other.m_x );
        m_ok = true;
        other.m_ok = false;
        return *this;
    }

    int m_x;
    bool m_ok;
};

struct B
{
    B( A& a )
        : m_a( a )
    {
    }

    std::reference_wrapper<A> m_a;
};

struct C
{
    C( int x )
        : m_a( x )
        , m_b( m_a )
    {
    }

    A m_a;
    B m_b;
};

int main()
{
    C oldc( 1 );
    C newc( std::move( oldc ) );
    std::cout << "C.A: " << newc.m_a.m_ok << " C.B.A: " << newc.m_b.m_a.get().m_ok << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not aware of a name for this pattern, but you don't have to define a replacement for the reference wrapper. Just add move constructors to `struct C`

```
struct C {
    C( int x )
        : m_a( x )
        , m_b( m_a ) { }
    C(C&& c) : m_a(std::move(c.m_a)), m_b(m_a) { }
    A m_a;
    B m_b;
};
```

See http://cpp.sh/374ca
Output is C.A: 1 C.B.A: 1

EDIT: I just realized that even the move ctor for B is not needed. Just this change to your `struct C` is more than enough to do what you are after. I have updated the link to cpp.sh. to point to the new solution.

Comment: Sure, that'll work fine.  What I'm really trying to guard against is people accidentally writing a C without realising they need that move constructor.  (i.e., that‘s what just happened, which is why I'm working on this )  I was thinking that giving B a different kind of reference that gets invalidated on a move would guard against that.

Comment: That is straight forward. Just do a `B(B&&) = delete` in your `struct B`. This will automatically stop `struct C` from ever being moved without explicitly defining the move constructor. You will get a compile time error on attempting to move `C`.